# Feature Importance extraction of Decision Trees (scikit-learn)

Tags: python, tree, scikit-learn, decision-tree, feature-extraction

I've been trying to get a grip on the importance of features used in a decision tree i've modelled. I'm interested in discovering the weight of each feature selected at the nodes as well as the term itself. My data is a bunch of documents.
This is my code for the decision tree, I modified the code snippet from scikit-learn that extract (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

### Feature extraction
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords,
                                 use_idf=True, tokenizer=None, ngram_range=(1,2))#ngram_range=(1,0)

tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(data[:, 1]) 
terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_features_names()
### Define Decision Tree and fit
dtclf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1234)

dt = data.copy()

y = dt["label"]
X = tfidf_matrix

fitdt = dtclf.fit(X, y)

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree

### Visualize Devision Tree

with open('data.dot', 'w') as file:
    tree.export_graphviz(dtclf, out_file = file, feature_names = terms)
file.close()

import subprocess
subprocess.call(['dot', '-Tpdf', 'data.dot', '-o' 'data.pdf'])

### Extract feature importance

importances = dtclf.feature_importances_

indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

# Print the feature ranking
print('Feature Ranking:')

for f in range(tfidf_matrix.shape[1]):
    if importances[indices[f]] > 0:
        print("%d. feature %d (%f)" % (f + 1, indices[f], importances[indices[f]]))
        print ("feature name: ", terms[indices[f]])
```

1. Am I correct in assuming that using terms[indices[f]] (which is the feature term vector ) will print the actual feature term used to split the tree at a certain node?
2. The decision tree visualised with GraphViz has for instance X[30], I'm assuming this is refers to the numerical interpretation of the feature term. How do I extract the term itself so I can validate the process I deployed in #1?

#### Updated code

```
fitdt = dtclf.fit(X, y)
with open(...):
tree.export_graphviz(dtclf, out_file = file, feature_names = terms)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @maxymoo UPDATED two lines of code

Answer (score 0):

For you first question you need to get the feature names out of the vectoriser with `terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()`. For your second question, you can you can call `export_graphviz` with `feature_names = terms` to get the actual names of your variables to appear in your visualisation (check out the full documentation of `export_graphviz` for many other options that may be useful for improving your visualisation.

Comment: the graphical output remains the same when I include feature_names = terms in export_graphviz. So it is still X[1] <= Value. I tried additional iterations like calling:                                                                                         `get_features() also features = (dict(zip(tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), tfidf_matrix)))`.   So the call function looks like: `tree.export_graphviz(fit_dt, out_file = file, feature_names=terms)`. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry i missed the problem the first time. you need to set `terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()`

Comment: I have that line, I must of deleted it from the post by accident. I rechecked and reran the code but the style X[#] <= Value doesn't change.